# What is the best format to display ebook on web page, PDF, ePub, or others in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, epub

I'm working on .NET project and want to display an ebook on web page, now I have a problem...

what is the best, easiest and fastest format to display it on web page, PDF, ePub, XML or others? Why? What API or library I should use?
Thanks

UPDATE:::

I got that PDF is tge best solution now and easy to use. Now can i display or view PDF file in Sliverlight, and have custom menu allow user to interact with PDF content?

Comment: What about simply using HTML?

Comment: As I remember ePub is basically HTML.

Comment: The requirement is: read eBook from some format (ePub, PDF, HTML, XML, DOC, or whatever) and display it on web page and preventing any users to get the source of eBook (copyright).-maybe using Flash or Silverlight or something can protect the book.

Answer (score 2):

The best and fastest is to display it as HTML. Why? Because HTML is what web was designed for in the first place, and it will allow users with any browser on any platform to read and access the book. XML as xhtml with css might also be a good choice.

The question is what format is the book originally in? If it's in PDF, then there are a lot of PDF to HTML converters out there, but nothing already built into the .net framework. If it's plain text, then creating html is easy.

Comment: I know ePub is HTML based and its the best and natural way to display an ebook as HTML. But of the main important feature is not allowed users to have access to the source, they just only read the eBook and have limited interaction with it.

Comment: Then I would go with PDF. It has options to disallow copy/paste and print if you need to restrict that. And most computers and devices have pdf readers. Another option is to render each page as a bitmap.